# print 1 to n number with out using second variable in java?

Tags: java, for-loop

print 1 to n number with out using second variable

i wrote like this

```
System.out.println("enter the input number");
int input = sc.nextInt();
```

one variable is input but we again we does't use another varible. so i stacked here.

if i write like this it display 1 to max value of Integer but here i am not taking input value

```
for(int i=1;i<Integer.MAX_VALUE;i++)
{
System.out.println(i);
}
```

if i write like this i taking two varibles

```
for(int i=1;i<input;i++)
{
System.out.println(i);
}
```

but i display up to max value of Integer number only but i want to display upto n number i.e what i given input number

Comment: i tried this but it asking every loop input i given 12 as input it display like this
1
12
2
12
3

Comment: its not working fine @Berger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use recursion to solve this problem , here is the function that do that, the output of solve(n) will be the numbers from 1...n :

```
public void solve(int n){
          if(n==0)return;
          solve(n-1);
          System.out.println(n);
}
```

Explanation:
Let's take an Example of n = 4 :

The Initial Call will be solve(4)

solve(4) will call solve(3) before printing anything.

solve(3) will call solve(2) before printing anything.

solve(2) will call solve(1) before printing anything.

solve(1) will call solve(0) before printing anything.

solve(0) will hit the base case as n=0 so it will return to solve(1) to continue its execution.

solve(1) will continue and print 1 then returns to solve(2)

solve(2) will continue and print 2 then returns to solve(3)

solve(3) will continue and print 3 then returns to solve(4)

solve(4) will continue and print 4 then returns to the caller of solve(4).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ahmed Amr

Comment: @Ahmed Amr Note: behind the scenes, recursion actually will actually give worse performance than a simple loop - it will actually create a stack containing n variables at most! And it will take more time because of function calling overhead

Comment: @Tejash Desai : Ofcourse Iterative Algorithms are better in most cases , but this is when you compare between 2 correct solutions to the same problem one of them is iterative and the other is recursive.

Comment: Thats true. I just wanted @HaiPandu to know that this approach actually takes more variables behind the scenes than iterative. But since its a Technical Interview question, it may pass :)

Comment: There is no other approach till now anyway than the recursive one, I'll think of an iterative solution but probably It's not there, also the calling stack is actually a one level lower in architecture , and whenever you go down in architecture you'll have more variables arise.

Comment: in program we take only one variable but stack internally takes n variables to store. at the time of interview i ask to my sir how can we solve it sir? he told me by using recursion we solve it. i think this is only one solution we have to print 1 to n numbers with out using a second varable

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your issue. It will print numbers 1 to i but in reverse:

```
while(i>0){
     System.out.println(i--);
}
```

By the way, Integer.MAX_VALUE is a constant, so if that is allowed, why not make i a constant and initialize another variable x which loops from 1 to i?

But why is this requirement of limiting variables, may I ask?

Comment: its my Technical interview Question. i don't know the answer so i post here. at finishing i ask my sit he told me use recursion to solve this . i tried but not solved this question

Comment: requirement to print 1 to n values not n values to 1.

Comment: so you can make n as a constant and loop another variable?

Comment: i thing constant is also a varible

Comment: They are, dont get me wrong. I never said they weren't. But you used a constant Integer.MAX_VALUE along with  another variable 'i' and said it is allowed. That is why I asked

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have imported java.util.Scanner like

```
import java.util.Scanner
```

now make sure you also have made an object from scanner like

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
```

this should work

Comment: its basic things to import package and creating object .i did it but don't works